# Debug HTML Email in Gmail App

Tags: html, email, gmail

Has anyone found a good way to actively debug HTML emails in the IOS Gmail app? Sending constant tests to a server is tedious, time consuming and does not allow me any debugging tools of course. I need a solution to actively solve all of Gmails little quirks.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586881/can-i-use-chrome-devtools-remote-debugging-to-inspect-an-email-in-the-android-gm

Answer (score 0):

Can can not debug HTML E-Mails in an easy way.
The best way to test emails is to use an automation tool to send emails to you for testing.
I used a grund / gulp plugin to send mails via mailgun (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mailgun).
For testing multiple clients at once, I recommend litmus (https://litmus.com/email-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the google workspace site for the solution. Here's a link that'll hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).