# Can I use Chrome Devtools remote debugging to inspect an email in the Android Gmail app?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

My html e-mail looks different on a browser than in the Gmail app, even with the same width, and I want to debug why. Is there some way to inspect the html elements within the Android Gmail app?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091456/debug-html-email-in-gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, email debugging is really difficult and in this specific case (as far as I know), there is no way to replicate how the Gmail App works on Android, on the web.

An option would be to use a tool like [Console.Re](http://console.re/), which is a remote javascript console, and try consoling your whole document or even specific parts of your interest, in case you can find anything useful to help you overcome your issue.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to do on the gmail app, but you can inspect element on the android browser. App like this can help you inspect the email: [Dev Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleverextract.devbrowser)